# http post redirect to login page at specific time even after session cookie is active in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, window, httprequest, webclient

```
1 > I login to a site using webclient successfully.
2 > Select some product to purchase.
3 > then request goes to bank page where i pay amount.
4 > After payment done it comes back to my site . but this time it gives login page.
```

I have looked into fiddler but cookies are same when it comes to site after payment from bank site.

**The main thing is that it happens at specific time like 2PM .** i am not able to understand what could be possibilities of this.

however I noticed one thing that when "Content-Type: text/plain" comes in fiddler then it gives login screen , but when "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" comes then it works fine . Is this issue ? if so then why this gives text/plain at that time and how to solve this issue.

Please help me on this. thanks in advance.

[Following are the fiddler request response detail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eADgf.png)

Comment: if i do same process at 2:30 it works fine.

Comment: I noticed one thing that when  "Content-Type: text/plain" comes in fiddler then it gives login screen , but when "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"  comes then it works fine . Is this issue ? if so then why this gives  text/plain at that time and how to solve this issue.